# Using JPA with Scala and Playframework

Tags: hibernate, scala, jpa, playframework

I have problem with Scala and playframework, I cannot use JPA:

#### `project/build.sbt`:

```
import play.Project._

name := """scala"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.2", 
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1",
  javaEbean,
  javaJdbc,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.1.0.Final" // replace by your jpa implementation
)

playScalaSettings
```

#### `conf/application.conf`:

```
# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG

db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.logStatements=true
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=memoryPersistenceUnit

ebean.default="models.*"
```

#### `conf/META-INF/persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="memoryPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

#### Entity `Task`:

```
@Entity
case class Task(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var idT : Long,

    @Required
    var nameT : String) extends {}
```

#### DAO Task:

```
object TodoDAO {

  def create( model : Task ) = JPA.em().persist(model)

}
```

When I run this application I have an exception:

```
PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Which version of Play are you using? Any reason to be adding both Ebean (javaEbean) and JPA (javaJpa) with Hibernate?

Comment: I tried doing this a while ago, but there doesnt seem to be an easy way to achieve this. You would be better off looking at Slick for scala. Its not quite as developed and easy to use as Hibernate, but should get the job done

Comment: It's 2.5.8, I tried Ebean and now I would like to try with JPA